A FastAPI project with asyncpg has dependencies from psycopg2, which causes the error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'
I have a FastAPI project that uses asyncpg to connect to PostgreSQL.
I use poetry and the following is my pyproject.toml files.
[tool.poetry]
name = "my_project"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["Me"]
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.10"
fastapi = "^0.104.0"
uvicorn = "^0.23.2"
sqlmodel = "^0.0.8"
asyncpg = "^0.28.0"
greenlet = "^3.0.0"
pytest = "^7.4.2"
pytest-asyncio = "^0.21.1"
httpx = "^0.25.0"
passlib = "^1.7.4"
python-jose = "^3.3.0"
python-multipart = "^0.0.6"
bcrypt = "^4.0.1"
black = "^23.10.1"
bandit = "^1.7.5"
alembic = "^1.12.1"
python-json-logger = "^2.0.7"
coverage = "^7.4.0"
pytest-cov = "^4.1.0"
cryptography = "^42.0.4"
python-dotenv = "^1.0.1"

[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]

However, I noted that when I run poetry install, the poetry.lock file generated has dependencies from psycopg2 in two pieces of the long file I am not going to past it all here.
mysql = ["mysqlclient (>=1.4.0)", "mysqlclient (>=1.4.0,<2)"]
mysql-connector = ["mysql-connector-python"]
oracle = ["cx-oracle (>=7)", "cx-oracle (>=7,<8)"]
postgresql = ["psycopg2 (>=2.7)"]
postgresql-asyncpg = ["asyncpg", "greenlet (!=0.4.17)"]
postgresql-pg8000 = ["pg8000 (>=1.16.6,!=1.29.0)"]
postgresql-psycopg2binary = ["psycopg2-binary"]
postgresql-psycopg2cffi = ["psycopg2cffi"]
pymysql = ["pymysql", "pymysql (<1)"]
sqlcipher = ["sqlcipher3-binary"]

Despite using asyncpg, there is a dependency on the no-async psycopg2.
Moreover, this causes another issue when I build a docker container for my project.
The following is the Dockerfile I am using.
# Base image
FROM python:3.10 AS python-base

# Environment variables
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 \
    PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1 \
    PIP_NO_CACHE_DIR=off \
    PIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK=on \
    PIP_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT=100 \
    POETRY_HOME="/opt/poetry" \
    POETRY_VIRTUALENVS_IN_PROJECT=true \
    POETRY_NO_INTERACTION=1 \
    PYSETUP_PATH="/opt/pysetup" \
    VENV_PATH="/opt/pysetup/.venv"

ENV PATH="$POETRY_HOME/bin:$VENV_PATH/bin:$PATH"

# Builder stage
FROM python-base AS builder-base
RUN buildDeps="build-essential" \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
        curl \
        build-essential \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends "$buildDeps" \
    && apt-get install -y iputils-ping \
    && apt-get install -y dnsutils \
    && apt-get install -y wget \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR $PYSETUP_PATH
COPY poetry.lock pyproject.toml ./

# Use the same version of Poetry as used locally
ENV POETRY_VERSION=1.5.1
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-o", "pipefail", "-c"]
RUN curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | POETRY_HOME=${POETRY_HOME} python3 - --version ${POETRY_VERSION} && \
    chmod a+x /opt/poetry/bin/poetry

RUN poetry config virtualenvs.in-project false
RUN poetry install --no-interaction --no-dev

# Development stage
FROM python-base AS development
ENV FASTAPI_ENV=development

COPY --from=builder-base $POETRY_HOME $POETRY_HOME
COPY --from=builder-base $PYSETUP_PATH $PYSETUP_PATH

WORKDIR $PYSETUP_PATH
RUN poetry install

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["poetry", "run", "uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]

and this is the docker-compose.yml one.
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: myuser
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: mypassword
      POSTGRES_DB: mydatabase
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  postgres_data:

As a result of running docker-compose up  I got the following error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/bin/uvicorn", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1157, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1078, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1434, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 783, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/main.py", line 416, in main
    run(
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/main.py", line 587, in run
    server.run()
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 61, in run
    return asyncio.run(self.serve(sockets=sockets))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 649, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 68, in serve
    config.load()
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/config.py", line 467, in load
    self.loaded_app = import_from_string(self.app)
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/importer.py", line 24, in import_from_string
    raise exc from None
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/importer.py", line 21, in import_from_string
    module = importlib.import_module(module_str)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/app/app/main.py", line 9, in <module>
    from app.router.api_v1.endpoints import api_router
  File "/app/app/router/api_v1/endpoints.py", line 3, in <module>
    from app.login.api import router as login_router
  File "/app/app/login/api.py", line 9, in <module>
    from app.core.security import create_access_token
  File "/app/app/core/security.py", line 15, in <module>
    from app.core.db import get_async_session
  File "/app/app/core/db.py", line 14, in <module>
    async_engine = create_async_engine(db_connection_str, echo=True, future=True)
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/asyncio/engine.py", line 43, in create_async_engine
    sync_engine = _create_engine(*arg, **kw)
  File "<string>", line 2, in create_engine
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/deprecations.py", line 309, in warned
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 548, in create_engine
    dbapi = dialect_cls.dbapi(**dbapi_args)
  File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/psycopg2.py", line 811, in dbapi
    import psycopg2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'


I checked with poetry show—-tree | grep psycopg2 to see if any of the installed packages have dependencies on psycopg2, and there are none.
Same with poetry show --tree | grep postgresql
I also tried to remove the venv and recreate everything from scratch without different results.
Do I need to add psycopg2 to the list of dependencies? If yes, why should it be necessary?
Moreover, If I install it, I got the following error
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: The asyncio extension requires an async driver to be used. The loaded 'psycopg2' is not async.


I managed to find the issue.
In the .env file, the string used to connect to the database was
DB_ASYNC_TEST_CONNECTION_STR="postgresql://postgres:pass/db_tests" 
Changing it to postgresql+asyncpg:// solved the error
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'
Nevertheless, in the poetry.lock, there are still dependencies from psycopg2.
`

The lines in poetry.lock are probably generated from optional dependencies in SQLAlchemy (which SQLModel is based on). They are thus not installed, but would be if you were to run e.g. poetry add sqlalchemy[postgresql].
